# JavaScript - Get Element with multiple values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a value from HTML. The HTML is inside a table:

```
      <td id="exchange_rate" class="center">
            <div class="exchange-sep">
            </div>
            <div class="exchange-sep">
                &#8644;
            </div>
            <div class="exchange-sep">
                <img src="https://.../graphic/resources.png" title="Pontos" alt="" class="" /> 1
            </div>
        </td>
```

What I want is to get what's inside the first div class. But it has an image and a value, and all I want is the value. From the console I get the info:

```
<img src="https://.../graphic.png" alt="">
" 614"
```

All I want is that last number.
When I run console with the next JavaScript, I get the image and number together, which doesn't solve my problem:

```
var racio=document.getElementById("exchange_rate").getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].innerHTML;
```

How do I get only the last number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var racio=document.getElementById("exchange_rate").getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].innerText.trim();`